# What happens behind the scenes to make `grep -R pattern` a valid command when `grep pattern` is not?

Tags: grep

I have noticed that when I do not specify a list of files for `grep` to search through, `grep` is much slower than when specifying filenames (even if the list is `*`, i.e. all the files in a directory).

This does not seem to happen when the `-R` options is used (`grep -R pattern` is as fast as `grep -R pattern *`).

I took the bad habit of calling `grep -R pattern` without a list of input files. I am now using `grep pattern` and I'm wondering:

What happens behind the scenes to make `grep -R pattern` a valid command when `grep pattern` is not?

Or, putting it another way, what is the difference between

1. `grep -R pattern`
2. `grep -R pattern *`
3. `grep pattern`

Comment: `grep pattern` is not valid - all that would do is wait for input on stdin

Comment: indeed; `grep pattern` would be nearly infinitely slow. What were the exact commands you were comparing?

Comment: Absent any context, I might guess that this is comparing `cat haystack | grep needle` against `grep needle haystack`?

Comment: I understand that `grep pattern` should be infinitely slow since it's waiting for input files. However, how come `grep -R pattern` works fine? Does `-R` implicitly feed input files/directories to grep?

Comment: GNU `grep` and its recursive option `-R` implicitly looks at the current directory and all the files in it or below it.  `grep -R pattern` is the same as `grep -R pattern .`, or if you don't have any hidden files in the current directory, `grep -R pattern *`.

Comment: `grep pattern` _is_ a valid command.  If no input files are specified (or implied as with `-R`), it looks for `pattern` in standard input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GNU `grep`, as well as some other implementations of `grep`, has a non-standard `-R`
option that makes it search the given files and directories recursively.

The GNU implementation of `grep` implicitly uses the current directory
if no other file or directory is specified on the command line when `-R`
is used.

```
grep -R PATTERN
```

is therefore the same as

```
grep -R PATTERN .
```

This would be the same as `grep -R PATTERN *` if there were no hidden
files in the current directory, or if the `dotglob` shell option had been
set in `bash`.  Without setting the `dotglob` shell option in `bash`,
the `*` pattern on the command line would only expand to non-hidden names.

Other `grep` implementations don't use `.` implicitly with `-R` even
if this would seem like a reasonable default since recursively grepping
standard input makes little sense.

This is `grep` on OpenBSD, as an example:

```
$ grep -R PATTERN
grep: warning: recursive search of stdin
```

Running `grep` without `-R` and with no input files will make the
utility read standard input. All `grep` implementations do this as this
is what [POSIX says the utility should do](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/grep.html).

So, running the (perfectly valid) command

```
grep PATTERN
```

with no input files would make `grep` wait for input from the terminal.
It would wait for input until you signalled end of input using
<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> or interrupted the process using <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

Reading from the standard input stream and recursively searching for
matching patterns in a directory structure are mutually exclusive
operations.  It would make little sense to do

```
somecommand | grep -R PATTERN
```

whereas

```
somecommand | grep PATTERN
```

is perfectly resonable.